# Woocommerce Product permalinks "product" word is not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I have facing one issue with Woocommerce Product permalinks.

When I used the "Product" keyword on Product permalinks at that time product detail page came with 404 not found.

[image]

Comment: Have you registered another product post type perhaps?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I check in the database? in admin i have checked but there is no any post for that name